# Combine all [ul], [ol], and [li] into a single tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I don't see why these are all split up. Separately, they don't really make any difference. In general, we're talking about "HTML Lists" and not an ordered or unordered list specifically. Whether or not it is ordered or unordered tends to make no difference with the questions, since oftentimes it's a CSS-related question about lists, which all use `list-style` and its sub-properties, or about nested lists, which aren't *specific* to either one (and usually get tagged along with [nested-lists](/questions/tagged/nested-lists)).

Going of the idea of being an **expert** in the tag, if you are an expert in any one of them you'd most definitely be an expert in all of them. A list item is *part* of a list, so there's definitely no point in having that separate tag. I propose that all of these tags be merged and/or synonymized into **one single** tag [html-lists](/questions/tagged/html-lists) (which makes most sense to cover them all). The tags that currently exist:

[li](/questions/tagged/li) **× 423**
[ul](/questions/tagged/ul) **× 382**
[unordered-list](/questions/tagged/unordered-list) **× 118**
[html-lists](/questions/tagged/html-lists) **× 82**
[ordered-list](/questions/tagged/ordered-list) **× 66**

**Note:** [list](/questions/tagged/list) and [listitem](/questions/tagged/listitem) are not related to this, although a few HTML list questions have used them.

It'd be preferable that synonyms be created for these so that users typing in "ul", "ol", or "li" can easily find the correct tag.

---

**Update:** I have gotten the tags to a place where [unordered-list](/questions/tagged/unordered-list) and [ordered-list](/questions/tagged/ordered-list) are currently suggested as synonyms of [html-lists](/questions/tagged/html-lists), but now we need either 4 people who have 5 votes in that tag or a moderator to push them through. I've also been going through the list of questions that are tagged with both [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [list](/questions/tagged/list) and converting to the correct tag.

Comment: Having the tags separate is a **huge** advantage for search.  Search for `ul`, and the results are worthless.  Search for `[ul]` and you're getting somewhere.  How the heck is a newbie supposed to know that he should search for `nested-lists` when ***he*** thinks that his problem is about `<ul>` elements?

Comment: @Brock: If they're synonymized, searching for `[ul]` would search for `[html-lists]`. It's pretty easy to find questions specifically about `<ul>` from the titles, and there are very few scenarios where they'd need to find a question *specifically* about unordered lists.

Comment: I did not know that synonym-search's worked like that.  It even works on the [Tags page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags). I withdraw my objection.

Comment: Ah, just about to ask this question. +1

Comment: I've synonymized [unordered-list] and [ordered-list].  Do you still want li and ul synonymized?

Comment: @Robert: Yes, I couldn't suggest those ones yet because they have more questions on them.

Comment: Hmm, looks like I don't have the ability to do that either.

Comment: @Robert: I was going to continue retagging [html]+[list] questions to get above the [ul] mark, push that one through, which would put it past [li] to push that one through too. Also, when do synonymized questions get retagged to the parent tag? Is it not instant?

Comment: I would have to merge them.  Right now they are just synonymized.

Comment: OK, I think I got it.  I merged [unordered-list] and [ordered-list] with [html-lists], and synonymized [ul] and [li] to [html-lists]

Comment: @Robert: Shouldn't those be merged in too? I think most questions which are tagged with [ul] are also tagged with [li].

Comment: @Robert: Cool, you should post your usual CW done answer so I can accept it. ;P

Comment: Do we need a synonym for [ol]?

Comment: @Robert: Umm, [ol] never existed but it could be useful, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed:

[li](/questions/tagged/li)
[ul](/questions/tagged/ul)
[ol](/questions/tagged/ol)
[unordered-list](/questions/tagged/unordered-list) 
[ordered-list](/questions/tagged/ordered-list)

are all now synonyms of [html-lists](/questions/tagged/html-lists)