# Should we favor a fewer number of more general tags, or a greater number of more specific ones?  Why?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

For some context, have a look at this meta question, and the comments below it:

[Merge the multidimensional-ish tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134417/merge-the-multidimensional-ish-tags)

Note that the OP is asking for a consolidation.  All of the tags that start with the words "Multi-Dimensional" would be merged into a single tag.

But is this the way to go?  And if it is, does it apply across-the-board?  In other words, is this a unifying principle of tag management?

Or is the unifying principle that all tags should have a single meaning, and therefore we should have a greater number of more-specific tags, as in [multidimensional-array] and [multidimensional-database]?

Or is it some other principle?  Or is there no unifying principle at all, and every tag merge/retag request must be handled on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: I vote for single meaning, with possibly a few rare exceptions. [tag:multidimensional] is too multidimensional to be useful, IMO.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Is [[html-lists](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-lists/synonyms)] one of those exceptions? Note that [this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123524/combine-all-ul-ol-and-li-into-a-single-tag) succeeded, but [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132012) failed.

Comment: I would even rate that as a single meaning, lists in html. I'm not convinced [tag:ordered-list] and [tag:unordered-list] should necessarily be synonymed, but no other programming-related use of those comes to mind, so I don't object. Similarly, [tag:unsigned-int], [tag:short-int] etc. belong to [tag:integer] and don't stop its meaning to be single enough.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a unifying principle and it should be based on usage.

**Example of a good general tag - argues for general tags**

I follow the very general tag [sql](/questions/tagged/sql). Its a top 15 tag with 80K questions and its got 11K followers. Even though it crosses many technologies you can effectively answers questions across all of them. People [have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107783/sql-tag-without-provided-rdbms) [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85709/popup-requesting-people-to-specify-a-dbms-when-they-tag-a-question-with-the-tag) that you shouldn't even be able to have this tag with specifying the RDMS and has been rejected.

**Example of a bad general tag - argues for a specific tag**

[vb](/questions/tagged/vb) is such an overloaded term that it [needed to be banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122968/can-we-permanently-ban-the-ambiguous-vb-tag) because people writing VB.NET code didn't want to answer Excel macro questions.

**Examples of *good* general tags that don't really work by themselves - also argues for a general tag**

Even though tags should be useful by themselves general tags [string](/questions/tagged/string), [array](/questions/tagged/array), [xml](/questions/tagged/xml), [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading) (all top 40 tags) really aren't. Instead these general tag are *extremely* useful for people who love to answer [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [string](/questions/tagged/string), but don't really want to answer [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [nhibernate](/questions/tagged/nhibernate). I also don't think anyone wants [string-c#](/questions/tagged/string-c%23), [string-java](/questions/tagged/string-java), [string-pascal](/questions/tagged/string-pascal) etc..

**tl;dr**
If we try to apply one reasoning for or against general tags to the wrong case we end up with a sub-optimal solution.

**On multidimensional**

Based on actual usage I think we should have [multidimensional-array](/questions/tagged/multidimensional-array) (3K questions)  and [olap](/questions/tagged/olap) (423 questions). The combination of [database](/questions/tagged/database) and [multidimensional](/questions/tagged/multidimensional) (3 questions) isn't really used and whoever brought that up was not being very helpful.

Comment: Uhh... The person who brought up the combination of [tag:database] and [tag:multidimensional] **was you.**

Comment: so you're saying *Some Helpful Commenter* was *not being very helpful*